# How to clone the html content using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html content:

```
<div data-test='sectionA'>
    <input type="text" />
    <strong>sfdsfds</strong>
    <p>dffdfdsf</p>
</div>
```

I need to clone only the `strong` and `p` elements from the html content above. Here is my attempt:

First I need to identify the section:

```
if($("div").data("test") == "sectionA")
{
     $(this).children().not("input").each(function()
     {
           alert($(this).html().clone());
           /* firefox says clone is not a function 
              and I'm not getting <strong>dfadfa</strong>
              or the <p>sfdasdfsd</p> clone copy */

      });
}
```

Comment: I'm not used to jQuery, but I think that `.html()` returns a string. And you can only clone HTML elements, not strings. Try removing that

Comment: `html` function returns string not nodes/objects so you have nothing to clone.

Comment: the clone copy should have been part of the comment

Answer (score 1):

```
var $div =  $("div[data-test=sectionA]");
var $strong = $('strong', $div).clone();
var $p = $('p', $div).clone();
```